# Javascript, validate object against exported type from npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, command-line-interface, npm-package

I developed a ClI npm package with TS that consumes a configuration file from a given path.

```
> tool --config="./path/to/config"
```

The configuration file exports a single object which my tool imports.
**Is there a way I can validate the imported object against a specific type definition?**

The tool has exported type definitions so I could force users to create their configuration file using TS and just reference the successfully compiled JS file.

But, are there any other options?
Would it be possible to have a JS file use a type from my CLI tool such that users would not have to install TSC wherever they wish to leverage my tool.

I came across Schemas, while writing this. Are they the best solution to my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to generate a json schema from your type definitions during the build step (using [typescript-json-schema](https://github.com/YousefED/typescript-json-schema) for example) and verify the config against such schema.